# Getting example in gulp-uglify to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify

I have never used gulp. I am trying out gulp-uglify example.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify

```
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('compress', function() {
  return gulp.src('lib/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

The example does not work. Where is `gulp.task` declared? What does the code inside `gulp.task` do? A file dist will be created after compressing all .js files in lib folder? How can the code example be modified to work properly?

Comment: Where are you files located? Is there an error message?

Comment: My js files are located in folder lib. There is no error message.

Comment: Please, remove this duplicate question, as you have another at http://stackoverflow.com/q/33708893/1363799

Comment: I cannot remove the question because you have already provided an answer.

Comment: Ok, I left a flag as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Working configuration

Gulpfile:

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src('./lib/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

package.json (run `npm install` to verify that all dependencies correctly loaded):

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "gulp": "~3.9.0",
        "gulp-uglify": "~1.5.1"
    }
}
```