# What is wrong with this code that combines multiple js files to one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, uglifyjs, gulp-concat

I have this node.js code that tries to minify and combine multiple js files to a single js file.

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    //gulp.src(['./lib/file3.js', './lib/file1.js', './lib/file2.js'])
    gulp.src(['./js/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

All my js files are located in js folder. My node.js file is above the js folder. I am expecting the single minified file to appear in dist folder. I see nothing and get no error message when I run the code. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Add `var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');`

Comment: I have done it. See the EDIT. Thanks.

Comment: I have added uglify line. Still the same result. Pulling my hair now. I am using Windows 7. Do I have to use Linux?

Comment: let me check, I'll be in touch within several minutes

Comment: Thanks. It is most kind of you. God bless you.

Comment: I'm ready, sorry for first comment - it was wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95133/discussion-between-alexander-and-user3293156).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Gulpfile.js:

```
"use strict";

var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify'); // Add gulp-uglify module to your script

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src('./js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

### Check package.json dependencies

Run `npm install` to verify that all dependencies correctly loaded. I think this was your issue:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "gulp-concat": "2.x",
        "gulp": "3.x",
        "gulp-uglify": "1.x"
    }
}
```

Comment: The fault was mine. I did not use gulp the right way. Confirmed your answer is right.

Comment: Answers are always more useful if they contain an explanation of what you changed or what was wrong in the OP's code rather than making the reader have to figure that out for themselves by comparing code.